# What do you call this kind of design?

Tags: user-interface, mobile-application

I don't know what to search for about this kind of design. I will use it on my app for the empty state, but I'm getting trouble searching. hope you can help me guys. Thank you :)

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Well the design type is "minimalist" or "modern" I'd say. If you are looking for a specific file format or something I think you'd be looking for SVGs (Scalable Vector Graphics).

Answer (score 0):

From trial and error, the best search queries are along the lines of **"Abstract Minimalist"** or **"Contemporary Art"**. Agreed, it is difficult to express to a computer what image you are trying to find.